# strtok() as a parameter in printf() printing value in reverse

Tags: c, string, printf, strtok

If you have a string as below

`str="insert 111,name,123456789"`

when you pass it to strtok and try to print the values, they are output in reverse. 
For example:

```
char* token=strtok(str," ");
printf("%s %s %s %s\n",token,strtok(NULL,","),strtok(NULL,","),strtok(NULL,","));
output: insert 1234567 name 1111
```

instead of:`insert 111 name 123456789`
Why is this happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: The argument evaluation order is not defined. Don't use code with side-effects (like calling `strtok`) in arguments.

Comment: Perhaps you are experiencing an *Indeterminently Sequenced* result because of the *sequence point* error, as there is no guarantee on the order of parameter evaluations. **C11 Standard Sect. 6.5.2.2 (10)**

Comment: How can it be fixed? by using the idiomatic `while(token != NULL)` loop. Your version is terrible also, because if one of the calls to `strtok` should return `NULL` you should not call it again. Never rely on input data being what you think it should be.

Comment: ... and you will be passing `NULL` for the `%s` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parameters are pushed to the stack in the Calling Convention order, which in your case, reverse... therefore parameter 5 is first to evaluate and pushed in the stack, then 4,3,2 and the format string.

as many comments before suggested, your call style is very discouraged,
and should be avoided.

Comment: And with respect to `x86_64` parameters passed by register -- how does that work out? (you should distinguish between integer arguments and all others)